# How to change the position of all figures to float

Tags: floats

I wrote following program to insert figures.

```
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[option]{file}
  \caption{hoge}
  \label{fig:hoge}
\end{figure}
```

I want to change positioxn of all figure environment to `[h]`.

Are there any good idea to change it?

EX: following is like

```
\renewcommand{\figureposision}{h}
```

Some TeX files are shared by some target files.

```
|- dir1
|   |- etc.tex
|   `- target1.tex
|- dir2
|   |- etc.tex
|   `- target2.tex
`- shared.tex
```

`\begin{figure}-\end{figure}` are in `shared.tex`.
The position option should be `[h]` in `target1.tex`, but `[]` in `target2.tex`

Comment: I would define a new environment `\newenvironment{myfigure}{\begin{figure}}{\end{figure}}`, use `\begin{myfigure}...\end{myfigure}` in `shared.tex`, and redefine `\renewenvironment{myfigure}{\begin{figure}[h]}{\end{figure}}` as appropriate.

Comment: You can reset the default placement using `\expandafter\def\csname fps@figure\endcsname{ht}`.  Note that [h] takes prescedence over [t] on the current page.